# Ordered Set is ordered in slicer but not ON ROWS

Tags: ssas, mdx, pyramid, olap

We have this named set:

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[Geography Alphabetical] as
{
ORDER(
[Geolocation].[Geography].[Geography Country].MEMBERS,
[Geolocation].[Geography].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME,BASC)
}, DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Geography Sets';
```

If we pull this into a slicer within our client (Pyramid) then the countries are in alphabetical order but if we put the set ON ROWS then they are back in hierarchical order.

How can we ensure that where-ever this set is used it will be in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a feature of the client software? To find this out, you can have a look at the MDX that it sends to the Analysis Services server using the Profiler tool as follows:

In the Windows start menu, select "Microsoft SQL Server "/"Performance Tools"/"SQL Server Profiler". Then select File/New Trace, connect to your Analysis Services server, and just click through the following dialog leaving the default settings.

You will then see each MDX statement sent to the server (and some other events as well).